# Typescript narrowing in not working with Cookies.get function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using js-cookie alongside with typescript and I'm getting stuck with types while trying to parse a cookie item:

```
// the item 'number' contains a javascript number (ex:5)
let n:number 
if(typeof Cookies.get('number')!== 'undefined'){
    n = JSON.parse(Cookies.get('number'))
}else{
    n = 0
}
```

**Typescript**: Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'

I'm following the basic example of typescript documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html

Am I making something wrong with this code snippet ?

Comment: How can the TypeScript compiler know that the result of `Cookies.get('number')` is going to be the same every time you call it?

Comment: There's also `JSON.parse(Cookies.get('number')??"0")`... and `JSON.parse` is overkill, why not just `+(Cookies.get('number')??"0")` or something like it?

Answer (score 0):

You have two calls of `Cookies.get('number')`. Typescript can not know that the same value is returned for both calls.

Therefore, save the value in a variable:

```js
let n:number 
let value = Cookies.get('number')
if(typeof value !== 'undefined'){
    n = JSON.parse(value)
}else{
    n = 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought that typescript will know that they refer to the same value. Thanks @md2perpe .

Comment: @aziz. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235